# In rails I can't display the new comment with iteration each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

I created a partial in post show#view which names _comments.html.erb

here it is

```
<p class="text-center">Poster un commentaire</p>
      <%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :content, label: "Commentaire"%>
        <%= f.submit "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
```

and it render like that `<%= render 'comments' %>`

and above the partial (in post show#view) I do an iteration like that

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <li>
      <p><% comment.content %></p>
   <% end %>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But nothing appears when I create a new message, I don't userstand why.

I give your more code details

**post.rb**

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

The route is:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :categories
  resources :comments
end
```

Comments controller is

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_post

def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "You commented the hell out of that post!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:alert] = "There is a problem with your comment"
    render root_path
  end
end

def destroy
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

  @comment.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Upon refreshing the page, does the new content appear?

Comment: **<p><%= comment.content %></p>**
 - Try **<%= %>** instead of **<% %>**

Comment: @ArslanAli the `=` missing

Comment: @dkp Yes it works thank you

Comment: I try to implement the destroy method like this :     `<% if @user.comment == current_user %>
                  <% link_to @post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>`                                                                                    And I have this message `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
...    link_to @post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: commen...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed the `=` in the erb template on the `<p>` line. Without it there won't be anything shown in the output. Also note that the `</li>` and `end` lines should be swapped so that these two blocks are not mixed together:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
     <li>
       <p><%= comment.content %></p>
     </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

By the way, there is another way to render collection partials like :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <%= render :partial => "comment", :collection => @comments %>
</ul>
```

And there is no need to loop through the values in partial, it will manage this with the `:collection` parameter, and then the comment partial should be like:

```
<li>
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
</li>
```